# relations between all kinds of initialization and constructions?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, c++14

I am asking if

```
Type t{...};
```

and

```
Type t({...});
```

and

```
Type t = {...};
```

are equivalent? If one works, the other should also work with the same results?

If no `explicit` modifier, are they equivalent?

Comment: It really depends on the `...` and what constructors are available.

Comment: No, all three are different. [Here's the example](http://rextester.com/REB74520) of the first one compiling while the other two don't.

Comment: And [here's an example](http://rextester.com/ZWA53068) where the second compiles, but not first or third

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The example serves its purpose of demonstrating that the three forms are not in fact equivalent. There was no requirement that the example "make sense", for some definition of the term. Having said that, in the world of brace-initialization, `explicit` does meaningfully apply to constructors taking more than one parameter.

Answer (score 7):

No, all three forms are distinct, and may be well-formed or ill-formed independently under different circumstances.

[Here's an example](http://rextester.com/REB74520) where first form compiles, but second and third do not:

```
class Type {
public:
    explicit Type(int, int) {}
};

int main()
{
    Type t1{1, 2};     // Ok
    Type t2({1, 2});   // error
    Type t3 = {1, 2};  // error
}
```

[Here's the example](http://rextester.com/REB74520) where second form compiles, but first and third do not:

```
class Pair {
public:
    Pair(int, int) {}
};

class Type {
public:
    Type(const Pair&) {}
};

int main()
{
    Type t1{1, 2};     // error
    Type t2({1, 2});   // Ok
    Type t3 = {1, 2};  // error
}
```

[Here's an example](http://rextester.com/YGKPC96080), courtesy of [@T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c), where third form compiles, but first and second do not:

```
struct StrangeConverter {
    explicit operator double() = delete;
    operator float() { return 0.0f; }
};

int main() {
  StrangeConverter sc;
  using Type = double;
  Type t1{sc};     // error
  Type t2({sc});   // error
  Type t3 = {sc};  // Ok
}
```

Comment: As an idea, make 1 ambiguous but 3 not by using explicit?

Comment: @Yakk `Type t3 = {1, 2};` is essentially `Type t3(Type{1, 2});` and so requires `Type{1, 2}` to compile - but then `Type t1{1, 2};` would also compile. I can't figure out any way around that.

Comment: Here's a [contrived corner case](http://ideone.com/cW42nF) in which the first and second forms both compile but do different things.

Comment: "I couldn't find a way to make the third form compile while the first does not". [There you go](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/752f6a732d08302a).

Comment: @T.C. Updated the answer with your example. I knew someone would see that and think ["Challenge accepted"](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/challenge-accepted).